# Creating a Form (Ruby on Rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I created a form in Rails 3.2 using the format below, but when I open the post view, I don't see the form to allow me post comments.  What could be wrong?

```
<%= form_tag(:controller => "posts", :action => "create") do %>  
  <%= label_tag(:message, "What are you doing?") %><br />  
  <%= text_area_tag(:message, nil, :size => "44x6") %><br />  
  <%= submit_tag("Update") %>  
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Rails 3 the form_* helpers return the markup rather than outputting it directly. Change:

```
<% form_tag(:controller => "posts", :action => "create") do %>
```

to:

```
<%= form_tag(:controller => "posts", :action => "create") do %>
```

Comment: But can i use something like `<%= form_remote_tag(:controller => "posts", :action => "create") do %> , this throws up an error

Comment: `form_remote_tag` was removed in Rails 3. Instead you can pass `:remote => true` in to the form_tag: `<%= form_tag {:controller => "posts", :action => "create"}, :remote => true do %>`

Answer (score 1):

Check your routes file and make sure it is correct. And do a = sign in your 1st row. Think that might work. But when you have a form for resource, using form_for is recommended:

```
<% form_for @posts.each do |p| %>
<%= p.label :message %><br />
<%= p.text_area :message, nil, :size => "44x6" %><br />
<%= submit_tag("Update") %>
<% end %>
```

Also, avoid < br/ >. Style your form with css (divs,classes etc). Of course , you'll have to make @posts var in your controller for this to work:

```
@posts = Post.all
```

Hope this helps

Comment: The error i got using your example is `undefined method `model_name' for Enumerator:Class` on line 1

Comment: maybe add equals sign like this <%= form_for @posts.each do |p| %>